# A PyQt5 button loads up data with np.loadtxt. Is there a way to store that data so I can make calculations later based on it?

Tags: python, numpy, pyqt5

First of all, I'm a beginner, so any impovement  you suggest is really appreciated. Using PyQt5 there is a button which loads up data with np.loadtxt. (It's unpacked into two arrays, because it's x-y data). What I'm trying to achieve is accessing (or storing) that data globally, so later on I can use it in other functions, for example Fourier transform it.

I've already tried to append them into a global np.array defined independently at the top, and also tried the tempfile module, but none of them worked correctly. Here is the function which is called upon clicking the button:

```py
def referenceArmClicked(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        referenceName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None,"QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()", "","All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        try:
            if referenceName:
                refX, refY= np.loadtxt(referenceName, usecols=(0,1), unpack = True, delimiter =',')

        except: 
            pass #it's just here to simplify the problem, I know it's a bad thing
```

If I put `self.refX`  and `self.refY` instead of `refX` and `refY`, I need to pass it to the function as arguments:

```py
def referenceArmClicked(self, self.refX, self.refY)
```

And this is when I connect the function to the button:

```py
self.iReferenceArm.clicked.connect(self.referenceArmClicked)
```

.. and it doesn't work, and I'm stuck.

The desired output should look something like this: np.array([refX, refY])
All I've got sor far are empty arrays.

Comment: if you need in functions in the same class then use `self.` - `self.refx`, `self.refY`

Comment: `except: pass` can be devil. Maybe you have error but you don't know it. Maybe all your problem can be resolved with this error message. You should at least display it `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: The except: pass is just there is simplify my question, but thank you.